# Terminating started Popen subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am on Windows and I am starting a new process using `subprocess.Popen` that I want to terminate at a certain point. However, the gui that I initiated is still visible. A minimal example would be starting the PNG viewer:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['start', 'test.png'], shell=True)
proc.kill()
```

After the `kill()` command the gui is still running and I have to close it manually.

As fas as I understood this can be solved on Linux by passing `preexec_fn=os.setsid` to `Popen` (see [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)). Since the command `os.setsid` is specific to Linux I do not know how to realize that on Windows.

Another way would be to get rid of the `shell=True`, however, I don't know how to realize that because I have to pass the file name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the `shell=True` you have to give the full path to the executable.

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('/full/path/start %s' % filename)
proc.kill()
```

Answer (score 1):

`start` is an internal command: it requires `cmd.exe` (that you could start using `shell=True` or run directly). `Popen()` does not wait for `start` command to finish and `start` does not wait for the PNG viewer to exit -- by the time you call `proc.kill()`, `start` might have finished already.

You could try to run PNG viewer directly instead (you don't need to provide the full path if the corresponding exe-file can be found in the standard locations).

[How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17614872/4279) has a solution for Windows too (you could try it if PNG viewer starts child processes).